# Vue-Multiselect - Deselecting group of pre-loaded values doesn't work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-multiselect

My code:

https://jsfiddle.net/bgarrison25/tndsmkq1/4/

Html:

```
<div id="app">
  <label class="typo__label">Groups</label>
  <multiselect 
    v-model="value" 
    :options="options" 
    :multiple="true" 
    group-values="libs" 
    group-label="language" 
    :group-select="true"
    placeholder="Type to search" 
    track-by="name" 
    label="name">
    <span slot="noResult">Oops! No elements found. Consider changing the search query.</span>
  </multiselect>
  <pre class="language-json"><code>{{ value  }}</code></pre>
</div>
```

Component:

```
new Vue({
    components: {
    Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
    },
    data () {
    return {
      options: [
        {
          language: 'Javascript',
          libs: [
            { name: 'Vue.js', category: 'Front-end' },
            { name: 'Adonis', category: 'Backend' }
          ]
        },
        {
          language: 'Ruby',
          libs: [
            { name: 'Rails', category: 'Backend' },
            { name: 'Sinatra', category: 'Backend' }
          ]
        },
        {
          language: 'Other',
          libs: [
            { name: 'Laravel', category: 'Backend' },
            { name: 'Phoenix', category: 'Backend' }
          ]
        }
      ],
      value: [
            { name: 'Laravel', category: 'Backend' },
          { name: 'Phoenix', category: 'Backend' }
      ]
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

So I have created a multiselect using groups. If its a fresh load with no pre-selected options it works fine. However, if you have values pre-selected and try to deselect the group they are in it simply doesn't work. Also, seems to be an issue if i deselect one manually and then select the group again.

Steps to reproduce in fiddle:

1) Laravel and Phoenix have been selected on load

2) click on the multiselect and choose "Other" to deselect the group. Nothing happens.

3) De-select "Phoenix" option and then click the "Other" group. Now you have "Laravel" / "Phoenix" / "Laravel" as options.

Wondering if I am doing something wrong or if this is a bug. If its a bug I will simply post in their issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your group deselect doesn't work, because objects that you predefined in your `this.value` don't refer to the objects in your `this.options`. They have the same structure and values, but they are different objects. To make your group deselect work with preselected values, set your `value` data property to `[]` by default, then add a `mounted` hook in which you preselect the "Other" group:

```
  mounted() {
    this.value = this.options.find(option => option.language === 'Other').libs;
  }
```

With this, deselecting "Other" with preselected values works.

As for your other problem where duplicates can be selected, I have never used Vue Multiselect, but the documentation describes events like `@select` or `@input` which you can probably use to filter out duplicates when needed. However, according to the docs, `trackBy` prop is used to compare the objects and it's weird that it doesn't work by itself.

Comment: The only problem here is that you are assuming here that "other" is always the selected group. However, I see your point. I need to find the selected values in options and let value equal that instead of new objects with the same values